# Python communicate is blocked after process kill

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I'm running a Python script that executes a Bash subprocess. If the Bash subprocess times out, then the Python script is expected to print the stdout of the Bash subprocess. The Python script works as expected, however, if the Bash subprocess is executed using the "sudo" keyword, then reading the stddout after the timeout blocks the Python.

The Bash script (named test-bash.sh) looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
        echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
        sleep 1
done
```

The Python script looks like that:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("sudo ./test-bash.sh", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=3)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    print("Succesfully killed")
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    print("Stdout: {}".format(outs))
```

The last print is never called, being blocked on communicate(), unless we remove the "sudo" from:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("sudo ./test-bash.sh", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What is the reason for the blocking of communicate()? How do I unblock it and read stddout() if I must run the Bash subprocess using "sudo"?

Comment: My guess would be that when the timeout occurs, Python is killing only the the shell it starts in which to run the `sudo` command, not the `sudo` command itself or the shell that it, in turn, starts to run your shell script.  `communicate()` then is not blocked, *per se*, it just doesn't see end-of-file on the subprocess's standard output, because the shell on the other end is still running and holding the write end open.

Comment: You could try `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=False, ...)`.  I'm not sure what you think you're gaining from interposing a shell between Python and the command you're running in the first place.  That might still not resolve the problem, however, because it peels only the outer layer from your three-layer onion.

Comment: Thank you. The guess regarding the killing of the outer shell was correct, but in my specific case, I couldn't get rid of the shell=True. The solution provided by Armali that proposes the kill the entire process group helped sort it out, regardless of whether the shell argument is set True or False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced even without `sudo` provided that `shell=True`. It's just like John Bollinger explained above, so I'll spare us the reciting. Fortunately `Popen` provides a means to deal with such multi-level subprocesses - it allows to start a new session and therewith to create a process group by which all subprocesses can be killed.

```
# add start_new_session=True argument
proc = subprocess.Popen(…, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, start_new_session=True)
…
# replace proc.kill() by
    import os
    import signal
    os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```